# Lazyloading on Website not Working. Local Food Startup needs Help :)

Tags: web, shopify, lazy-loading

We have a Shopify Store and I am trying since days to get lazyload working.
Everything is set up but it just won't lazy load.

Can someone maybe check my website and tell me what's causing it not to lazyload the images even though the class is there and the js is installed?

Thanks

[www.aho.bio](http://www.aho.bio)

I just need i hint where to search. I can do the hard stuff myself ;)

Comment: [Check Here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6bc3c1a0733cda338b329865167f9f1f20210310080036/a396b4), it works well when you scroll it update the images. I think you need to check the default image size is currently 200px;

Comment: your front page has lazyload working.  how do you know it is not working? which page?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=de&url=www.aho.bio

Comment: It says defer non visible images

Comment: I checked again and mny pictures DON't have the lazyload attribute.

Comment: Do you know a way how to add the lazyload class to all images in my shopify shop?

Comment: You can add a class to all images using javascript

Comment: Hey Funk Doc, thanks for the answer. I tried several ways so far. Without javascript and with javascript to fetch all the img tags and slap a class onto them. But all the scripts I found didn't work. I out them just before the end of the body in the theme.liquid file. But unfortunately my pictures didn't get the class added to them. Do you have an example of code that will add the class lazyload to all img tags

Comment: @Alex the best way is to use only liquid code - this is how we do it. Do you still have that problem? Just went through your site and found out that some images still don't have lazy sizes initialized. Let me know if I can help.